# How to grab a value from a url with multiple values using PHP. [2 Part Question]

Tags: php

This is a two part question. First how can I grab the last url value from a link when I dont know how deep the value is, for example how can I grab 
the last value of `sub_4` from the link example below using PHP? And second how can I grab the url value `cat=3` and the last url value `sub_4` using PHP?

I'm kind of new to PHP so a detailed step by step example would help me out a lot if its not too much trouble.

Thanks in advance!

Here is an example of a URL value.

```
http://www.example.com/categories/index.php?cat=3&sub_1=sub1&sub_2=sub2&sub_3=sub3&sub_4=sub4
```

Comment: Do you only want the "sub_X" where X is the greatest number?  So, if there were a sub_5 included, you would only care about that?

Comment: @sberry2A I would like all the values if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All variables from the hook will be returned on $_GET. So if you want to get that value from the URL, just use:

```
$_GET['sub_4']
```

If you want to get a list of all of the possible values:

```
array_keys($_GET)
```

This will give you all of the variables.

UPDATE: I just reread your question. I think I better understand what you are looking for. Correct me if I am wrong, but you are not certain how to get the last element of the string? Is that right? So you could potentially have sub_5, sub_6, sub_7 etc. Here is how to get the last element from the string:

```
end($_GET);
$key = key($_GET);
$last_item = $_GET[$key];
```

`$last_item` will now have sub_4 (or what ever the last item is).

Answer (score 1):

#### Extracting URL Parameters

Query parameters (anything in the URL with `?name` or `&name`) are saved in the [`$_GET` superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php).

If `sub` is a hierarchy, you should probably just write it as such.  For instance: `?sub=path/to/sub` or `?sub=path:to:sub`

From this you can [`explode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) on your separator (`/` or `:`) to get the different parts of the `sub` parameter. `$sub_array = explode('/', $_GET['sub']);`

You can then iterate over the array using a [foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) or directly access the highest branch of the hierarchy using [count()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php):

`$sub_array[count($sub_array-1)];`

#### Building URL Parameters

If you have an array of subs that you want to use to generate a URL, you can use [`implode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to build your URL params.  `$sub_params = implode('/', $_GET['sub']);`

You might construct that array by appending each `sub` to the `$sub_array`.

```
$sub_array[] = 'sub1';
$sub_array[] = 'sub2';
$sub_array[] = 'sub3';
etc.
```

#### Inspect the Data

If you get lost, use `var_dump($_GET)` or [`var_dump($variable)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) to see what's inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Each `cat=3` or `sub_1` value can be retreived by `$_GET['cat']` and `$_GET['sub_1']` respectively. To elaborate, `$_GET['NAME_OF_PROPERTY']` would look like `php.net/index.php?NAME_OF_PROPERTY=whatever`

It seems like both questions were on how to grab the value from the URL, so I hope that answers both.

In your example url http://www.example.com/categories/index.php?cat=3&sub_1=sub1&sub_2=sub2&sub_3=sub3&sub_4=sub4

```
echo $_GET['cat']; // 3
echo $_GET['sub_1']; // sub1
echo $_GET['sub_2']; // sub2
echo $_GET['sub_3']; // sub3
echo $_GET['sub_4']; // sub4
```

Comment: that means i will have to use $_GET[] about 10 times if there are ten sub values is there a better way so I can no where the last sub value is?

Comment: `array_pop(array_keys($_GET))` will give you the last item listed in the `$_GET` array

Answer (score 0):

For the first part; you should use the $_GET[] array which contain every parameter passed in the url `$_GET['cat']`, `$_GET['sub_1']`.

For the second part, in your case you should try send an array in parameter like this :

```
http://www.example.com/categories/index.php?cat=3&sub[1]=sub1&sub[2]=sub2&sub[3]=sub3&sub[4]=sub4
```

And then use the `$_GET['sub'][]` array `$_GET['sub'][1]`, `$_GET['sub'][2]`, ...
Now you can determine the length of the array and know the last item in it.

Answer (score 0):

This example is under the assumption you want to find the very first variable in the GET query, and the very last:

```
<?php
// Here, you separate all the variables
$parameters = explode("&", $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);

// Get the last key's index
$last_key_index = count($parameters)-1;

// Easy way for PHP 5.3
$first_key = strstr($parameters[0], "=", true);
$last_key = strstr($parameters[$last_key_index], "=", true);

// Bit longer otherwise
$first_key = substr($parameters[0], 0, strpos($parameters[0], "="));
$last_key = substr($parameters[$last_key_index], 0, strpos($parameters[$last_key_index], "="));

// Test it here
echo($first_key);
echo($last_key);
?>
```